# React function doesn't update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like at the start of startStop(), "secs" would equal "remaining". then set state "remaining" to equal "secs" at the end of the interval. However, the "secs" does update each 1000 millisecond, but setState for "remaining" does not actually update. Does it has to do anything with secs only update within the nested function decrement()? How to get "remaining" to update?

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    timerState: "paused"
    remaining: 1500,
  }

startStop() {
    
    var secs = this.state.remaining

    function getminutes()  
      return Math.floor(secs / 60)
    }

    function getseconds() { 
      return secs - Math.round(getminutes() * 60)
    } 

    function appendZero(number) {
      if (number <= 9)
        return "0" + number
      else
        return number
    }

    const decrement = () => {
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = appendZero(getminutes())
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = appendZero(getseconds())
        secs = secs - 1
    }

    if (this.state.timerState === "paused") {
      this.setState({
        timerState: setInterval(() => decrement(), 1000)
      }, 
      this.setState({
        remaining: secs
      })
    }
    
    else if (this.state.timerState !== "paused") {
      clearInterval(this.state.timerState)
      this.setState({
        timerState: "paused"
      })
    }

    this.setState({
      remaining: secs
    })
  }
```

Comment: State is supposed to be immutable. By including a function in it, you've violated that one golden rule of react programming.

Comment: Could you elaborate on which code that violates the state immutability? I thought I only use setState() which is allowed to manipulate state in this case?

Comment: State should affected by external code, which ensures that a new state is created (via `setState`) whenever it is changed, thus keeping state immutable. If the state object itself is calling functions that update something else's state (in this case the UI), or itself, then there's no immutability and you end up with bugs galore. It might be okay to have the structure you're developing, but I would suggest that perhaps React is not the library you should be using to do it.

Comment: I'm learning react so would like to make this work with it. As you can see, I need state "timerState" to toggle start / pause on the interval and "remaining" to keep track of the time. I don't know where else to declare variables for those purposes, unless I put them in the functions but then they are not available for other function to access, thus I chose state. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
   this.setState({
            timerState: setInterval(() => decrement(), 1000)
          }, 
          this.setState({
            remaining: secs
          })
```

to:

```
this.setState({
        timerState: setInterval(() => decrement(), 1000),
        remaining: secs
      })
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. Still not update.

Comment: Probably because you are trying to set a function to a state variable. Try setting the state like this inside `setInterval`

Comment: One more thing, add `timerState` to your state when you first declare it `state = {
    remaining: 1500, timerState: null
  }`

Comment: I actually have timerState in state. I don't understand the purpose for "null", I set it as "paused" so that the startStop() can start the interval when it first see timerState as "paused".

Comment: That `timerState` in state was literally not there when I commented that. It can be seen in your edits as well?

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work. I moved the setState to increment() as below:

```
const decrement = () => {
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = appendZero(getminutes())
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = appendZero(getseconds())
        secs = secs - 1
        this.setState({
          remaining: secs
        })
    }
```

Still don't understand why it doesn't work if setState() at the end of startStop() as my original question?